# How to call overrider controller from html form

Tags: php, model-view-controller, overriding, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Like in topic. How can I call the overrider controller from html form like this below:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php?controller=CmsController">
    <input name="test" type="text" />
    <input name="action" value="getStatus" type="hidden" />
    <input value="test" type="submit" />
</form>
```

This code above I have in my tpl file.

File: /override/controllers/front/CmsController.php

---edit

```
{$link->getModuleLink('blockcms', 'CmsController')|escape:'html'}
```

doesn’t work.

---edit

```
public function initContent() {
    parent::initContent();

    if (Tools::getValue('action') && Tools::getValue('action') == 'getStatus') {
        $id = $this->getIdByCode(Tools::getValue('voucher'));
        $obj = new CartRuleCore($id);
        $context = Context::getContext();
        $response = $obj->checkValidity($context);
        if ($response == NULL or $response == 'Koszyk jest pusty'){
            $response = 'Kod ';                
        }
    }

if (isset($this->cms)) {
            $this->cms->content = str_replace("<!--response-->", $response, "{$this->cms->content}");
        }
        $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_ . 'cms.tpl');
```

This is part of initContent function in \override\controllers\front\CmsController.php And in my file tpl I have

```
<form method="post" action="index.php?controller=CmsController">
<input name="test" type="text" />
<input name="action" value="getStatus" type="hidden" />
<input value="test" type="submit" />
```

Comment: The overrided controller is loaded automatically from PrestaShop autoload system. What do you want to do? It's not very clear...

Comment: OK. In /override/controllers/front/CmsController.php I have code which check voucher in my shop. Where is the problem ? I want to send voucher from this form above to this controller. So I need action in this form, right ?

Comment: Please post in the question what have you done :)

Comment: Please go to post above I add new text.